# How do I get a Texas Instruments ACX 111 wireless card working?

Tags: drivers

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 and I have a Texas Instruments ACX 111 wifi card.

I have looked at a few topics about how to get the drivers for it, though, all the download links don't work...

Does anyone here know where I can get these drivers.

Here is a link to the one of the first topics I read

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/acx111

The driver's link and firmware link doesn't work.

Comment: Ubuntu tries its best to include drivers. Does the wifi work? What error messages do you get?

Answer (score 2):

I found this driver

http://www.bijteam.com/drivers-texas-instruments-acx-111-802-11g-wireless-network-adapter/

It works

And I followed this guide

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

Answer (score 1):

Adding this in case anyone else has an old acx wifi card and is having trouble getting it to work on ubuntu. (14.10)

After driving myself nearly insane trying to get ndiswrapper to work the instructions here https://wiki.debian.org/acx did the trick for me.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please edit your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material..

Answer (score 0):

I just had in my hands n°two D-Link AirPlusG+ (chipset ACX111) after my office changed the computers.
I installed both under linux with no problems:
the 1st one is working with ubuntu 12.04, the 2nd one with Puppy 5.x.
In both cases the driver is the original one, from the installation CD, installed with ndiswrapper given from the ubuntu distribution (for Puppy i used Puppy's SMS) taking care to choose the XP driver (the others don't work).
With Linux Lite (an Ubuntu based distribution) i wasn't able to make it work.
The adapter works with lan WEP and WPA, not with wpa2.
The test with WPA was done with the original AP from Dlink and an AP from Alice (Italian adsl company)
the test with WPA was unsuccesfull with AP USR462.
The PW should be of 10 or 13 characters lenght.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by batFINGER, if you're using 14.x and ndiswrapper won't work (in my case with AirLink101 AWLH 3025 which uses Texas Instruments ACX 111 chipset), the instructions at https://wiki.debian.org/acx may work for you. Worked first time for me on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

As suggested by Ravan, perhaps that link will one day disappear, so here's an overview:

acx-mac80211 is an experimental, reverse-engineered, out-of-tree Linux kernel driver for wireless LAN devices based on Texas Instruments ACX100/TNETW1100, ACX111/TNETW1130, ACX100USB and TNETW1450 chipsets. It is developed by the [acx100 project](http://acx100.sourceforge.net/).

**To list your PCI network devices use**

```
lspci -nn | grep Network
```

**To list your USB network devices use**

```
lsusb
```

**Compatible devices**

```
PCI: 104C:8400 Texas Instruments ACX 100 22Mbps Wireless Interface
PCI: 104C:8401 Texas Instruments ACX 100 22Mbps Wireless Interface
PCI: 104C:9066 Texas Instruments ACX 111 54Mbps Wireless Interface
USB: 0451:60C5 Texas Instruments, Inc. (Device name unknown)
USB: 057C:5601 AVM GmbH AVM Fritz!WLAN [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
USB: 057C:6201 AVM GmbH AVM Fritz!WLAN v1.1 [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
USB: 07B8:B21A AboCom Systems Inc WUG2400 802.11g Wireless Adapter [Texas Instruments TNETW1450]
USB: 0CDE:0017 Z-Com (Device name unknown)
USB: 2001:3B00 D-Link Corp. AirPlus DWL-120+ Wireless Adapter [Texas Instruments ACX100USB]
USB: 2001:3B01 D-Link Corp. WLAN Boot Device
```

This driver supports the WPA and WPA2 security protocols. Non-free firmware is required for device operation.

**Install the firmware**

For ACX 100, [specific firmware](http://acx100.sourceforge.net/wiki/Firmware) is needed.

To install all firmware versions for ACX 111, use:

```
$ sudo suAlternate installation methods are described within the repository's INSTALL file.
# for i in "" c16 c17 r16 r17 ; do wget -P /lib/firmware http://acx100.erley.org/fw/acx111_1.2.1.34/tiacx111$i ; done
```

To install firmware for ACX100USB use:

```
# wget -P /lib/firmware http://acx100.erley.org/fw/acx100_1.0.9-USB/tiacx100usbc0D
```

To install firmware for TNETW1450 use:

```
# wget -P /lib/firmware http://acx100.erley.org/fw/acx111_2.4.0.70-USB/tiacx111usbc1B
```

**Installing the driver**

Driver installation can be automated with DKMS.

Check out the repo:

```
$ git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/acx100/acx-mac80211 acx100-acx-mac80211
```

Move to correct location

```
$ sudo su
# mv acx100-acx-mac80211 /usr/src/acx-mac80211-git
```

Add acx-mac80211-git to the tree for building and installing:

```
# dkms add -m acx-mac80211 -v git
```

Build and install the acx-mac80211 module:

```
# dkms build -m acx-mac80211 -v git
# dkms install -m acx-mac80211 -v git
```

Load the module:

```
# modprobe acx-mac80211
```

If necessary, connect the device to your system.

[Configure](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse) your wireless interface as appropriate.

Alternate installation methods are described within the repository's INSTALL file.